# Angular throwing error with Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

On safari, angular is throwing a weird error **Requested keys of a value that is not an object.** when I call the function below. It works fine on chrome and firefox but on safari not so much. I even made console.log calls to see where the error was and if the $scope.id was returning a value to pull all the other data from this ID...tested a few things to no avail.

```
app.controller('ViewOneArtist', function($scope, $http, $resource, artistesUrl, baseUrl, $stateParams) {

$scope.artistesItemsResource = $resource(baseUrl + artistesUrl + $stateParams.id, {id: "@id"},
    { create : { method: "POST"}, save: { method: "PUT"}}
);

$scope.id = $stateParams.id;

console.log($scope.id);

console.log("got to here...before listOneArtiste");

$scope.listOneArtiste = function(id) {
    $scope.artistesItem = $scope.artistesItemsResource.get(id);
};

console.log("got to here...after declared listOneArtiste");

$scope.listOneArtiste($stateParams.id);

console.log("got to here...after calling listOneArtiste");

});
```

Console.log is returning a value from $scope.id or $stateParams.id (ex.: 43) but when I call the function listOneArtist() it throws the error above. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well after testing several items I fixed it myself here is the solution:

```
app.controller('ViewOneArtist', function($scope, $http, $resource, artistesUrl, baseUrl, $stateParams) {

$scope.artistesItemsResource = $resource(baseUrl + artistesUrl + $stateParams.id, {id: "@id"},
    { create : { method: "POST"}, save: { method: "PUT"}}
);

$scope.id = {id: $stateParams.id};

$scope.listOneArtiste = function(id) {

    id = this;

    $scope.artistesItem = $scope.artistesItemsResource.get(id);
};


$scope.listOneArtiste($scope.id);

});
```